# max() function not working properly in laravel querybuilder

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to get maximum column value of table using query :

```
$today = Carbon::today();
    $o_no = Prev_order::whereDate('date_time',"=", $today)->max('ord_no');
    if($o_no){
        $o_no = $o_no + 1;
    }
    else{ $o_no = 1; } 

    $orders = order::where('table_no', $request->table_no)
                    ->where('dish', $request->dname)
                    ->first();      
    if($orders != null)
    {
            $qty = $orders->dish_qty + $request->dish_qty;
            $data = [
                'dish_qty' => $qty,
            ];
            $orders = order::where('dish', $request->dname)->update($data);
    }
```

`return response()->json($todr);`

but it is not giving max value after 9, means if max value is 10 it is giving max value as 9... I am not geting what is wrong exactly.
actually am increasing value after each submit button i.e order no. when I check previous max value(order no) i added 1 in it and updating new order no. but here when value is 10 it is often adding value as 10 only, when i checked max() function it is giving max value as 9 only, whats wrong exactly.

Comment: try this reference link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073214/laravel-query-builder-where-max-id

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that you are getting data from table first then you are updating order no. So in that case even if order no has changed in database you will not get upgraded order no that is maximum value or else please share some code so that it will help to understand even better.

I don't think there is problem with max function, if you think max function is not working properly then you can try a different query.

```
DB::table('orders')->where('id', DB::raw("(select max(`id`) from orders)"))->get();
```

And if you are using Eloquent models.

```
$order = Orders::whereRaw('id = (select max(`id`) from orders)')->get();
```

Comment: it is working properly till no 1 to 9 but when value is 10 it is still giving max value as 9.

Comment: when i use get() i am getting whole row, i just need that max value so that i can update next order number as u can see

Comment: hey i solved it.. actually it was problem with table structure.. i just changed the type to INT from VARCHAR and it is working fine now..... thanks

Comment: ok yeah you have to take integer type for that if you want perform any operation like + ,- on the value store in db.sounds good.