# Laravel get highest value of each column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.5, And I want to know how can we get highest value of each column in one query ?

Is that possible or we should query one by one ?

I tried below code.

```
DB::table('family')->max('children')->max('salary');
```

When I tried just `DB::table('family')->max('children')`, It works well. But when I try `DB::table('family')->max('children')->max('salary')`, I get below error

> Call to a member function max() on string

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please see this guide on how to ask questions on Stack Overflow: [Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher i didnt try anything because i didnt know how to do that , just asked question to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get either by single query.

```
$result = DB::table("family as f")
->select([DB::raw('MAX(f.children) AS children_max'),DB::raw('MAX(f.salary) AS salary_max')])
->groupBy('f.id')
->first();
```

Or using separate `->max()` method.

```
$family = DB::table('family');
$max_children = $family->max('children');
$max_salary = $family->max('salary');
```

Get more details in [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073214/laravel-query-builder-where-max-id) and in [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#aggregates)

Comment: you are a hero works very well , but which method you prefer for higher speed?

Comment: Although second solution is cleaner but first is faster, use according to your use, first is preferred.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but I just suggesting you, always add your try, I am adding your comment in your question

Comment: @user2468 Okay , i see , Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Add `max()` with your eloquent to get the maximum value of each column value.

```
ModelName::select(DB::raw('MAX(column1) AS colum1'),DB::raw('MAX(colum2) AS colum2'))->get();
```

check this laravel  [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#retrieving-results)

**Edit:**
You can do it with query builder in laravel.

Comment: when i try DB::table('family')->max('children) it works well , but when i try DB::table('family')->max('children)->max('salary') the result is "Call to a member function max() on string"