# Return only the highest equipment maintenance id

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I want to get the highest `maintence_id` for `equipament` to show to a user. I can do this in SQL, but not in Eloquent or QueryBuilder.

Eloquent returns all the maintences for my view:

```
$equipament = Maintence::SELECT('maintences.*', 'equipaments.patrimony as patrimony')
            ->LEFTJOIN('equipaments', 'maintences.equipament_id', '=', 'equipaments.id' )   
            ->get();
```

SQL returning the highest `maintence_id` for `equipament`:

```
select * 
from  equipaments
left join maintences on maintences.equipament_id = equipaments.id 
and maintences.id = (select max(id) from maintences as main 
where 
main.equipament_id = equipaments.id )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking after:

```php
Equipment::select('equipments.id', 'equipments.name', 'maintenances.id as maintenance_id')
        ->leftJoin( \DB::raw(
            '(select max(id) as id,equipment_id as equipment_id  from maintenances group by equipment_id order by id desc) maintenances'
          ), 'maintenances.equipment_id', '=', 'equipments.id')
          ->get();
```

I assume your table names are `equipments` and `maintenances`, if not, please adjust the table names accordingly within the provided query.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend you use inner query inside JOIN clausule or either in SELECT one... It will run it for "each" rows. It's better you declare on Model Class a relation who will get the last one. See code above:

```
class Equipament extends Model {

 //Declaration of relation with Maintence
 public function maintences() {
  return $this->hasMany(Maintence::class);
 }

 //Ddeclaration of last Maintence relation filter
 public function lastMaintence() {
  return $this->maintences()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(1);
 }

}
```

Then you can use like this:

```
$equipament = Equipament::with('lastMaintence')->find(1);
$lastMaintence = equipament->lastMaintence()->first();
```

Comment: I'll try it! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
Maintence::join( DB::raw(
    '(select max(id) as id,equipament_id as equipament_id  from maintences group by equipament_id order by id desc) sub'
  ), 'sub.equipament_id', '=', 'equipaments.id')
  ->get(['maintences.*']);
```

Comment: Return this error: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'equipaments.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `maintences`.* from `maintences` inner join (select max(id) as id,equipament_id as equipament_id  from maintences group by equipament_id order by id desc) sub on `sub`.`equipament_id` = `equipaments`.`id`)

Answer (score 0):

Have a the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073214/laravel-query-builder-where-max-id).
Always search for problem using more simple term as possible. It's works! :)

About the problem.
Why max ID and don't last version of equipament, for example?
Check what you really want because sequence ID, for example, necessarily isn't the more updated.

Comment: Thanks for your help Rafael. I'll check this the next time!